# How to place block in top of beamer poster

Tags: beamerposter

Why when I write empty block in beamer poster, that block was placed in center of frame. How to place that block in the top of frame, eventhough that block empty.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>
  {
% you can chose your theme here:
\usetheme{Berlin}
% further beamerposter themes are available at 
% http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php
}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\Large Introduction}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.3 \textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\Large Result}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.3 \textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\Large Simulasi}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the postion specifier  `[t]` for `\begin{frame}` also like

```
\begin{frame}[t]{}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>
  {
% you can chose your theme here:
\usetheme{Berlin}
% further beamerposter themes are available at
% http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php
}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}                     %%% <--- here
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\Large Introduction}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.3 \textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\Large Result}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.3 \textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\Large Simulasi}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]